# Вызов Uber Russia из стороннего приложения

Tags: android, android-intent

у YandexGo есть возможность вызова из стороннего приложения:

```
        Android.Net.Uri uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "yandextaxi://"));
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, uri);
        intent.SetPackage("ru.yandex.taxi");
        _activity.StartActivity(intent);
```

Есть ли такая же возможность открыть приложение Uber Russia?

Comment: написать вместо ru.yandex.taxi имя пакета убера

Comment: писал, имя пакета "ru.yandex.uber". проблема в том, что не понятно, что писать вместо "yandextaxi://"

Comment: вот такая ошибка: Android.Content.ActivityNotFoundException: 'No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=yandextaxi:// pkg=ru.yandex.uber }'

Comment: попробуйте для начала получить имя пакета, потому что получается что вы вызываете несуществующий пакет

Comment: Ммм, а почему вы решили, что у Uber Russia пакет называется ru.yandex.uber?

Comment: @Эникейщик по ссылке в магазине google play https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.yandex.uber

Comment: @Эникейщик так же с помощью команды "adb shell pm list packages" в adb консоли вижу такое же имя пакета

Comment: Хех. ну какой же это тогда убер. Попробуйте заменить yandextaxi на yandexuber

Comment: я уже очень много вариантов соединить эти имена попробовал, ни 1 не подошел. А где взять информацию о том, какое имя это должно быть я не знаю. Хотя пример успешного вызова uber russia из стороннего приложения есть.

Comment: к слову, обычное приложение uber таким способом успешно запускается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо "yandextaxi://" нужно использовать "ubermlbv://". Имя пакета "ru.yandex.uber".

```
    Android.Net.Uri uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "ubermlbv://"));
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, uri);
    intent.SetPackage("ru.yandex.uber");
    _activity.StartActivity(intent);
```

Видимо, после того, как uber слился с яндексом, имя приложения, по которому его можно вызвать из другого приложения, изменилось. Новое имя приложения можно посмотреть, открыв uber russia -> информация(в боковом меню) -> о приложении. и внизу мелким шрифтом будет написано текущее имя приложения